# How much time should I allocate for transiting from the flight gate to the train station at Munich Airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-transfer, muc

I am travelling from Johannesburg to Munich, I land at 07h00 and need to catch the earliest train from Munich to Vöcklabruck Austria, whats the earliest train i can take taking into accounts customs and baggage collection?

Comment: Highly relevant: 10 Minuten! According to the former president of Bavaria if they would have buildt the transrapid: "Dann starten Sie praktisch hier am Hauptbahnhof und das bedeutet, dass der Banhof näher an Bayern heranwächst." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7TboWvVERU

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you land at 7 sharp, and assuming there are other flights landing pretty much around the same time, I would suggest you to keep a buffer time of 2-2.5 hours. Whenever I have reached Munich, it took me 30-40 min to come out, but there have been cases when I waited for more than 1.5 hours when I went to receive my friends because there were 3-4 flights landing around the same time and few people at the passport control.

Once you are done with all these formalities, you need to take the S Bahn aka Suburban Train (look for a big green symbol with S written in white. You can buy the ticket at the airport itself. This walk to catch S Bahn + getting tickets totally must take you around 10 min max. There are frequent trains going to Munich central station where you need to catch your train to Austria. This journey to central station takes about 30-40 min if I am correct.

To save time, you can get the tickets to Austria online. Check Deutsche Bahn or OBB website. You can then catch the 9:28 one or the 11:28 one to Salzburg, and change trains to your destination: Vocklabruck, depending on how quickly you are done with passport control and baggage collection.

Have a safe journey!

Comment: Munich airport has usually about 30-40 arrivals per hour. What do you mean with '3-4 flights landing around the same time'? Buying a separate ticket for the suburban train is just more expensive and unneccesary effort. The cheapest option is to buy a through ticket from Munich Airport to Vöcklabruck. There is also the option to transfer in Munich East (München Ost) instead of at the main railway station, leaving you with a reasonable hourly connection from the airport to Vöcklabrück, departure about 30 minutes after each full hour and 3:30 travel time.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo 3-4 international planes might clog passport control for good. In my experience tho, German passport controls are pretty fast, compared to e.g. French and Italian.

Comment: @alamar Of all arrivals in Munich, some 10-15 flights per hour come from non-schengen countries, so 3-4 flights are landing around the same time *all* the time - it is the rule and not an exception.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo as of time of writing, MUC airport has only 4 non-EU flights between 14:00 and 15:00, that is, Cairo, Belgrade, Sarajevo and Pristina. I imagine that international flights are not distributed evenly but clustered at certain hours (morning and evening probably). That makes passport control clogging more dangerous if anything.

Comment: @alamar What are you trying to point out by counting flights from non-EU countries?